# RESTful service: PUT or DELETE

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture

When implementing soft row deletion by setting its status to `deleted` which method is appropriate? 
Should it be `DELETE` for we are not passing that row to `GET` anymore or should it be `PUT` for we are updating the row's status to `deleted`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If from the perspective of the user, the resource is not accessible after 'soft deleting' it, (e.g.: you would return a 404), use `DELETE`. If you can still `GET` the object after, I don't think I would use `DELETE`, but `PUT` may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Marking for deletion should be on the client side, only POST to the server when you do a proper delete.

If you want to contact the server and do another GET in the meantime - you should do the delete at that point. i.e. your GET should get the latest data, meaning the delete should be done before the GET.